# Converting AJAX to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

How would you convert following code to use only jquery library?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function do_it(value)
{
function newXMLHttpRequest()
{
   try{ return new XMLHttpRequest(); }catch(e){}
   try{ return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){}
   try{ return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }catch(e){}
   return null;
}

var ajax_request = false;
ajax_request = newXMLHttpRequest();
var url = "test.pl?b64="+value;
    ajax_request.open("GET",url,1);
    ajax_request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(ajax_request.readyState == 4)
        {

            var response = ajax_request.responseText;
            document.getElementById("in").innerHTML = response;

        }
    }
    ajax_request.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="text" name="string" onkeyup="do_it(this.value)"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div style="position:absolute;width:200px;height:200px; background-color:yellow; margin-top:100px;" id="in"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry, I probably should have mentioned that I don't actually have any practical experience with jquery, and I am in process in familiarizing myself with it now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at jquerys [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - i think thats what you're looking for:

```
function do_it(value){
  $('#in').load('test.pl', { b64: value });
}
```

**EDIT:** if you want to have different error- and success-handlers, using [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) like others posted would be the way to go - but for qa simple get-this-and-put-it-into-that-div-request, load() is more short and easy.

**EDIT2:** to your comment: the best would be to to identify your input field in any way (give an id to it, or give the same class to every field that should get this event) and then simply do:

```
$('#mytextfield').keyup(function(){ // with id-selector
  do_it($(this).val());
});

$('.textfield').keyup(function(){ // with class-selector
  // whatever
});
```

(not: i havn't tested that, just writing out of my mind... if there's a problem, just take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page))

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Can't believe one line replaced all of the code... Also how would you go around implementing the onkeyup event in jquery?

Answer (score 4):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.pl?b64=' + value,
  success: function(data) {

      // document.getElementById("in").innerHTML = data; 

      $("#in").html(data);  // jQuery way instead of above line

  }
});
```

Note: not tested, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out what this code is doing.

Comment: Why not use jQuery to set the html, too? `$("#in").html(data);`

Comment: `document.getElementById("in").innerHTML = data;` in jQuery is `$("#in").html(data);`.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the onkeyup javascript event with jquery as well, I know there is such an event in jquery as well, not entirely sure how to implement it though...

Answer (score 2):

```
function getData(service, successFunction, failureFunction, getDataType) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        cache: false,
        url: service,
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            failureFunction(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);  //Pass error details to the failure function
        },
        success: function(data) {
            successFunction(data); //pass data to the success function
        },
        dataType: getDataType
    });
}
```

Something like that, where the service is the URL, the successFunction is the one you do something with the data, and the dataType is the expected type of data you will be receiving.

[JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

This might seem a little overwhelming, I'm sorry I tend to use closures so I only have one or two generic AJAX functions (GET and POST), for anyone interested here is a sample function calling the getData Function above

```
function getUserLabs()
{
    function successFunction(data){
        userLabs = new Array();
        $.each(data, function(i,item){
            var labID = data[i]['pk'];
            var labName = data[i]['fields']["name"];

            userLabs.push(new Array(labID, labName));
        });
    }

    function failureFunction(data) {
        alert("Data not received");
    }

    getData('lab/summary/', successFunction, failureFunction, 'json');
}
```

Comment: You can simply use `error: failureFunction, success: successFunction` instead of wrapping it with another anonymous function. Additionally I'd not call the argument `XMLHttpRequest` but `xhr` as `XMLHttpRequest` is the name of an existing class.

Answer (score 2):

The most similar jQuery function would be [$.Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
$.get('test.pl?b64=' + value, function(data) {
  $('#in').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To help reduce code footprint, I prefer to use jQuery.post(). You can read more about it
here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Actually, you specified "GET" as your method, so the better option here is jQuery.get(). You can read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Example:

```
$.get("test.pl", { b64: value },
    function(data){
         document.getElementById("in").innerHTML = data;
     });
```